# ActiveModel::Serializers with nested objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, activemodel

I'm working on the rails API application which is using ActiveModel::Serializers. The problem I faced is that I'm not able to create a single response format for all calls with usage of `ActiveModel::Serializers`. I tried several approach. One of them was to create an object which will be responsible for the result rendering `Response` with a serializer like that:

```
class ResponseSerializer < ActiveModel:Serializers

attributes :result, :error

end
```

Then to the result attribute, I'm assigning an object which has a custom serializer assigned (`ObjectSerializer`).

The problem is that when I'm calling explicitly `render @object` then the custom serializer is called, but when I'm assigning an `object` to the Response object which is using then ResponseSerializer class the result attribute generates the json without calling an `ObjectSerializer` class. Could anyone help with such issue ?

Answer (score 0):

what about making your `ObjectSerializer` inherit from your `ResponseSerializer` ? Or use a mixin ?

Comment: I tried such approach but still ends up that I'm not able to put the error in the same node as the response if I'm inside objectSerializer class. Or the other way around. I'm not able to get the custom serializer rendered in any child node different then root.